# Monitoring CPU and disk utilization of a single program

Tags: c++, c, windows, monitoring

How can I calculate CPU and disk utilization of another concurrent program?  I.e. one program is running and other calculates the first's resource use.

I'm using C and C++ and running under Windows XP.

Comment: "I want the code" is something you say when you're a manager of programmers at a company. You know, work. We help, not work. :)

Comment: GMan: Too true. Have I been so inured that my eyes reinterpret that now?  I do think it is common for non-English speakers to use that phrase when they mean they want help or to know which APIs ("the code") are useful.

Comment: @Roger: Yeah, I agree it's not what he intended. :) I'm actually curious what utilities exist for this kind of programming.

Comment: @Gman: i want the logic behind the process.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, as Process Explorer can do it, but I think you will have to use some kind of undocumented Windows API. PSAPI comes somewhat close, but it gives you only the memory usage information, not CPU or disk utilization.