# How to measure peak memory size etc. during a given interval in Windows

Tags: windows, performance, winapi, memory, memory-management

With `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX`, I can find the peak pagefile (VM) size since the beginning of a process. Can I somehow get the peak pagefile size starting from some other point in time?

Comment: You can fix this problem like any other Windows problem - reboot the machine.

Comment: :) No, that wasn't quite my intent. Clarified the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this: [PerfSetULongCounterValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373125%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? I have not given it a try myself  but judging from the description `This is a convenience function for setting raw counter data.` and from [Process Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780836%28WS.10%29.aspx) it might be what you are looking for. I see what you are using `PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX()` but it is likely that in order to change counters you need to use directly [Performance Counters Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373078%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Anyway, this is just an idea to try. Also you can find this post useful [Monitoring CPU and disk utilization of a single program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475341/monitoring-cpu-and-disk-utilization-of-a-single-program/2476676#2476676).

Comment: So it is not suitable, is it? Is there any other function?