# getting cpu usage of one process using c++ (win32)

Tags: c++, windows-xp, cpu, cpu-usage

How i get the cpu of one process (by its id or som thing like that...) using c++ lang.

Answer (score 1):

One of ways: [Monitoring CPU and disk utilization of a single program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475341/monitoring-cpu-and-disk-utilization-of-a-single-program/2476676#2476676)