# How to wait for a process to finish C++

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I am creating a process with that code:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, "process.exe", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, %ini_processo, %processo_info);
```

I need my code to wait for my process to finish before resuming. What is the method with C++ ?

Comment: Maybe I have leaks with my search skill.

Comment: WaitForSingleObject(processo_info.hProcess, INFINITE).  Don't forget to CloseHandle() the returned handles.  And it looks like you ought to be using the Process class if % actually compiles.  Use & otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. I begun to learn C++ a week ago and been searching for this solution since yesterday.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846385/running-a-windows-program-and-detect-when-it-ends-with-c

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You just call [`WaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) on the handle [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) returns.

Comment: It returns a boolean which signifies whether the operation succeeds, not a handle.

Comment: @RonKan handle is returned through the PROCESS_INFORMATION out parameter.