# Need to hook a process in C++

Tags: c++, process, hook

i want to do a simple program that will run another program (easy task in C++), hook the process and, when the program is closed, run another program (needed to sync a file modified by the first program).
The second program prompt out a popout asking a simple Yes/No buttons.
There is any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "hook" and what have you tried so far, and how do your requirements deviate from calling `std::system` twice?

Comment: This varies according to platform.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running a Windows program and detect when it ends with C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846385/running-a-windows-program-and-detect-when-it-ends-with-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044654269&id=1043284392

It lists the various ways you can run another program.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing an article about hooking : http://ntvalk.blogspot.nl/2013/11/hooking-explained-detouring-library.html

It describes the probably most common methods for hooking under Windows. (jmp/vtable/etc)

gldraphael already described a method of running another program.